# SIGSEV Error in Priority Queue insertion function in C

Tags: c, priority-queue

I'm trying to create a routine to insert the values of a struct in a reagular queue, however, the insertion is based on priority. 
For some reason I'm getting a SIGSEV error in the algorithm though. Here's the code along with the struct declarations.

```
void p_queue_insertion(Queue *f, int cpf_c, int cpf_t, char opr, int priority) {    

int i = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < f->size; i++)     //f is a pointer to a dynamically 
    {                                //alocated array of queues.
        if(f[i].pri == priority);
        {
            Block* new_client = (Block*) malloc(sizeof(Block));

            if(f != NULL)
            {
                f[i].size++;
                new_client->c->cpf_client = cpf_c;
                new_client->c->cpf_terceiros = cpf_t;
                new_client->c->op = opr;
                new_client->c->pri = priority;
                new_client->next = NULL;

                if(f[i].start == NULL)
                f[i].start = new_client;

                else
                f[i].start->next = new_client;

                f[i].end = new_client;
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case, the queue is being implemented as a linked-list, like this:

```
typedef struct queue
{
    Block *start, *end;
    int size;
    int pr;  //pr = priority of the queue.
} Queue;
```

The struct "Block" was declared as:

```
typedef struct block
{
    Client* c;
    struct block* next;
} Block;
```

And finally, the struct Client has been declared as:

```
typedef struct client
{
    int cpf_client, cpf_terceiros, pri;  //pri = priority of the client.
    char op;
} Client;
```

This is the information the debugger has returned, and it also highlighted the line where it says "new_client->c->cpf_client = cpf_c;"

```
   0x0000000000401d0a <+154>:   mov    0x18(%rbp),%edx
=> 0x0000000000401d0d <+157>:   mov    %edx,(%rax)
   0x0000000000401d0f <+159>:   mov    -0x10(%rbp),%rax
```

I apologize in advance if it's just a simple stupid mistake, but I'm really having a tough time with this one. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a weird place to be checking `if(f != NULL)`. If `f` is `NULL` you will never make it there, since accessing `f->size` is UB. You should check if `f` is `NULL` before you dereference it.

Comment: What do you think `f[i]` would do if `f` is a pointer to a single `Queue` structure? If `f` is the root of a linked list, you can't use array indexing with it. It seems you could need to take a couple of steps back, and start over by reading about pointers and basic data-structures.

Comment: You don't allocate memory for `c` object in `Block` structure.

Comment: Thanks for the answers everybody. The error actually was that I allocated a block instead of a Client, therefore the program did not know who the client inside of new_client was. After I corrected that and messed around a bit more, the program is working fine.